# Safari and WebKit async anonymous function execution differences

Tags: javascript, function, lambda, parameters, safari

Running this code on Chrome and Safari would be different. Notice, function is async.

```
(async function(v) {
    console.log(v)
})('@')
```

Safari out:

```
1 - '@'
```

Chrome out:

```
1 - '@'
```

Now it look ok, but what if we add some.

```
(async function(v) {
    console.log(v)
    var v = v || '#';
    console.log(v)
})('@')
```

Safari out:

```
1 - undefined
2 - '#'
```

Chrome out:

```
1 - '@'
2 - '@'
```

There are no more passed V as parameter, its voided even right after function body starts. It seems Safari lefthand operator runs first and replace all passed params with the new ones that are  defined in a scope. Is this a bug?